# How can I preload a page I want to navigate to?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am building an app for WP8, and the MainPage.xaml takes a couple of seconds to load.
I want to add an animated Splash Screen, so here's what I did:

- I created a new, and set it as the default navigation page
- I put a StoryBoard animation in the page, with nothing else around, so that it loads fast

Now if I try to navigate to the main page from this page, it takes a couple of seconds becouse it has to load all the content as always.

A user here on stackoverflow wrote a sample of code to do something like this, saying that if you create a new instance of the page before navigating to it, it will cause the page to actually preload, making the navigation really fast.
Here's his code:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    var sb = new Storyboard();
    // create your animation here

    sb.Completed += (sender, args) => PreLoad();
    sb.Begin();
}

private void PreLoad()
{
    // this is the part that actually takes time and causes things to get loaded
    // you may need it in a try/catch block depending on what is in your constructor
    var page = new PageToNavigateTo();

    // now create an animation at the end of which we navigate away
    var sbOut = new Storyboard();
    // create your animation here

    sbOut.Completed += (sender, args) => NavigateToNextScreen();
    sbOut.Begin();
}

private void NavigateToNextScreen()
{
    // navigate here
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

    // remove the loading screen from the backstack so the user doesn't see it again when hitting the back button
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

I just don't understand what he means with the line:

```
var page = new PageToNavigateTo();
```

What am I supposed to do there? I mean, which method do I have to call to create a new instance of the page I want to navigate to?
Also, inside the NavigateToNextScreen() method, do I have to use the usual

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/CreditiInfo.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

or something else?
Could you help me completing this code? :)

Thank you!

Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that 'PageToNavigateTo()' should be the page constructor for the name of your next page. So in your case you would have:

```
var page = new MainPage();
```

For the navigation. That is the only way, that I know of navigating between pages on a Windows Phone 8 application.

Comment: Ok, that should be what he meant, but it looks like navigating to the new page with the usual NavigationService.Navigate... doesn't work. I mean, it works, but it loads for a couple of seconds.
Which method do I have to use to navigate to a page I've already created?

Comment: May I ask what the reason is for the couple of second delay?. Are you having to load some data into the page before you display it?. Like I said that is the only way I know of navigating between pages, I will have a look and see if I can figure anything out.

Comment: I don't know, I have a panorama app with 6 pages, and there are a lot of textbox, textblocs, gauges and stuff. At first it loaded in less than a seconds, but as I started adding things to the panorama, the startup time got longer, I suppose that's normal.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't suspect that simply adding usercontrols should slow down the loading period greatly. How many controls do you call 'alot'?. I think I found the original post that you got the code from. I believe what he is trying to say is that by simply calling the constructor before you navigate you will pre load. However I'm not sure that will work as once you navigate, you will be navigating to a new instance of the page. Also the code was aimed at WP7, which i believe used a different navigation structure than WP8.

Comment: Ok, so that's why it doesn't work :(
Right now I have (in that 6 pages Panorama): 52 Buttons, 49 Grids, 7 animated Gauges, 88 TextBlocks, 63 rectangles, 26 TextBox, about 30 StoryBoards and some other stuff. I honestly don't know if it's normal that the app takes a couple of seconds to load with this number of controls...

Comment: I can't say I have ever had a single application page that contains so many user controls. But as all you are doing is simply loading the page and initialising the controls, I would imagine it would be normal. Why do you have so many controls on one page?

Comment: Nono, those are not on a single page ahahahah
They are all the controls I have in the six Panorama pages and in the LayoutRoot Grid above the Panorama. I wanted an app that was easy to use and with everything in a single panorama, without having to navigate through different pages, so this is the result :)
So the only think I can do is create a static SplashScreen with an image, or leave the app with the black "loading..." default page?
EDIT: I was wrong, I don't have 52 buttons, but like 10-12.